# Xcode 8 Memory Graph says "No selection" and not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

I am working with a project using Xcode 8.0 and Swift3.

I want to use Memory Graph Debugger but it shows nothing:

[image]

Expected appearance (from tutorial):

[image]

Why can't I use this feature?

This project was created using Xcode 8 (not migrated from old version of Xcode).

Is bitcode related to this problem?

I am trying to use Memory Graph with "Debug" configuration and bitcode on "Debug" is enabled(YES).

Comment: I'm getting this problem too... Except, it works in the app until I follow a certain procedure (opening a particular UIViewController and dismissing it). Then I get "No Selection"... :(

Answer (score 14):

Computer restart is what you have to do.

It happened for me too, and no amount of tweaking the settings fixed it - disappointingly, the only thing that worked was a complete restart of the computer.

Comment: Amazingly, this was the fix for me too.

Comment: This worked for me too. I also want to note that happens frequently for me - meaning it's not a situation where you just installed Xcode and it doesn't work. I need to reboot my machine a few times a day, whenever I get this message.  Thanks for the tip. I never would have thought to try this!

Comment: I know, it's disappointing as what would be a really useful feature has again been underwhelmingly implemented by Apple. I'm afraid that repeated restarts are not really an option for me as I have too much open, so I'm sticking with Instruments :(

Answer (score 9):

This could be because you haven't enabled the things that need to be enabled for your requirements. You could try these two steps:

- First, launch scheme editing by clicking on "Edit Scheme" as in this screen shot:

[image]

- Second: go to "Diagnostics" and enable the things that you need to work (sometimes I need these two things):

[image]

- Close out of editing schemes and try again.

Props to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823322/how-to-enable-visual-memory-debugger-in-xcode-8?rq=1#answer-37827530) for shaking my own memory awake on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Restart computer is nor work for me.

And it can work on simulator, so I try to restart my device, and it worked.

on Xcode 10.

**Restart your device**

Answer (score 0):

Changing to a different simulator helped in my case.

I have not done any detailed research but still I wanted to share my solution; I had the same problem recently with Xcode 9.4.1 / Swift 4.1. Restarting the computer did not help in my case. However, changing the simulator to 'iPhone 7 - 11.4' (I had used 'iPhone 8 - 11.4' before) solved the problem in my case.