# "Memory Graph Debugger: no serialized memory graph received from LeakAgent" error when using Xcode Memory Graph Debugger

Tags: xcode, memory-graph-debugger

I'm using Xcode 10.2.1 and macOS Catalina Developer Beta 2. Whenever I try to use the Memory Graph debugger, I get this error:

> Memory Graph Debugger: no serialized memory graph received from LeakAgent

[image: Memory Graph Debugger alert]

After that, the loading spinner spins indefinitely.

[image: "Building Memory Graph" loading screen]

I've tried the answers recommended under [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40500625/3151675), but unfortunately, none of them worked. I tried to reinstall the app; restart Xcode, the iOS Simulator and my computer; deleted the DerivedData folder, and tried different simulators - none of these worked.

Answer (score 25):

I've observed the same error when did try to start memory graph using Xcode 11.2.1 (macOS Catalina 10.15.1) and **iOS 12.2** Simulator.

Starting memory graph debugger with latest simulators (**iOS 13.2.2**) works fine.

Comment: I think this answer should be selected as the best answer. I checked and indeed it works on iOS 13.2.2, but does not on iOS 12.2.

Comment: The old sims should still work tho. This is an Apple bug!

Comment: Well I need to test leaks in a feature for an older iOS version.

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim you might try to use instruments -> leaks instead

Comment: @ilya It crashes when I stop recording.

Answer (score 20):

You should use a **physical device** rather than a simulator to avoid this error.

Comment: I am getting this with a physical device running iOS 13 and Xcode 11.4.1.

Comment: The `leaks` command line tool does not work on a *physical device*.

Comment: This answer implies that using the simulator is somehow erroneous, which it isn't. This issue _shouldn't_ occur when using the simulator, but it appears to be the result of a bug:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/115628

Answer (score 12):

Faced the same issue recently after updating to Xcode 12.5 while being on macOS 11.2.3

The [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12_5-release-notes) for Xcode 12.5 mention:

`In macOS 11.2 or earlier, leaks and other command line analysis tools fail or crash when run against processes built with Mac Catalyst and processes running in iOS 14.5 or later on simulated devices. (74690398)`

**Updating to macOS 11.3** helped resolve this issue with the `leakagent`.

Answer (score 9):

The above answers didn't work for me. But this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823322/how-to-enable-visual-memory-debugger-in-xcode-8?rq=1#answer-37827530) did. As the linked answer mentioned:

1. Disable the **address sanitizer**
2. Enable the **malloc stack**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This just happened to me with iOS version 14.5 after the Xcode update.

If you **download another working simulator** (e.g. the previous version), you can get the graph from that version.

Downloading Simulators can be done from the bottom of the device selector:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was using a simulator for iOS 12 while latest was iOS 14